# Auth errors using Apache HTTPClient

Tags: java, authentication, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to make a request via an authenticated proxy as follows

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("http-proxy", 80);
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(
            user, password));

    try (CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build()) {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
        post.setConfig(config);

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        return response;
    }
```

My issue is that it's giving me the following errors, which I don't quite understand. I suspect I might not be using the right classes to do the authentication.

```
    WARNING: NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))

WARNING: KERBEROS authentication error: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)

WARNING: NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
```

Comment: I don't know much about HTTP authentication in general, but these messages mean that your client does not know which kind of auth the proxy expects, so it tries SPNego *(among other things??)*, first with Kerberos then with NTLM. And both fail.

Comment: BTW why do you try to handle a proxy as if it was some kind of regular HTTP site?? Java has a specific toolkit for proxies, i.e. `Proxy` and `SocketFactory` and the like. I remember using that stuff for FTP and SFTP connections (using Apache commons.net and SSHJ - both support custom `SocketFactory`).

Comment: The apache examples had me handling the proxy this way. Are you suggesting I try to rewrite this using the out of the box java.net api?

Comment: _[shrug]_ Have it your way. But I'm afraid the Apache examples work great with Apache toy proxies and Apache toy web sites; the real world is a bit more complicated. By the way, did you simply try `curl` with the appropriate proxy parameters and debug traces, to see what kind of auth / headers it uses?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm familiar with curl

Comment: *[sigh]*  `curl` is a standard package in any Linux distro, has Windows ports that can be downloaded freely, has a user manual, etc. If you prefer `wget` then go with that one. And if you prefer to do nothing and sit in your couch gloomily, well, that's your life choice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong with MS proxy server configuration. You can [disable NTLM in HTTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442177/disable-ntlm-on-apache-httpclient-4-3-6) and try basic authentication or if NTLM/Kerberos is mandatory try [HTTP wire logs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html) to throubleshoot the problem further.